# How do I troubleshoot "GET https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/a94k1e4g.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"?

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, ssl

Hello I am fairly new to troubleshooting SSL errors, but have spent over an hour searching on this already with no luck.  I'm using my personal MacBook Pro at work for iOS and OSX testing on a secured wifi connection, but whenever I try to test a dev page that uses sublimevideo player the page errs out & these errors described below continue to elude me.  I just don't know where to begin.  I tried looking for bad certificates or related certificates in my keychain but I only saw Apple related certs there.  Clearing my cache and resetting the browser did not help, nor did turning off all extensions.  Google has not been much help either unfortunately.

I have Charles installed but I don't see anything that jumps out at me when I do a test reload with it open...

**UPDATE:  I tried to load the file in a new browser window and it didn't even load there.  I've tried loading the domain to see if I would get any kind of response and I did not.  There is a less secure guest wifi, which I tried loading the js file on also, and it did so just fine so I'm doubtful it's anything on my own computer.  I am starting to think this is a firewall blocking all connections with a white-list of sorts, but that is just my best guess.**

What are some ways I can find the source of the problem?

Chrome:

```
>GET https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/is/a94k1e4g.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR                                    sublime_video_widget.js:63
>GET https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/is/a94k1e4g.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR                                    sublime_video_widget.js:63
>Uncaught ReferenceError: sublime is not defined                                                    sublime_video_widget.js:194
```

Safari:

```
ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: sublime
Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.            https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/a94k1e4g.js
Failed to load resource:  There was a problem communicating with the secure web proxy server (HTTPS).               https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/a94k1e4g.js
```

Mobile Safari:

```
Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.                https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/a94k1e4g.js
Failed to load resource:  There was a problem communicating with the secure web proxy server (HTTPS).               https://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/a94k1e4g.js
ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: sublime                                                sublime_video_widget.js:63
```

Comment: Mobile Safari provides the best clue: "ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: sublime" and "sublime_video_widget.js:63"

Comment: The variable comes from the a94k1e4g.js so if that's what you're referring to it's only a side effect, rather than a clue/lead - I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https Mixed Content errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451124/https-mixed-content-errors)